# ASP.NET Session not synchronising between threads on update?

Tags: asp.net, session, thread-safety, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a controller method that returns some JSON. It's pulling a collection out of session, taking the first item one from the collection and then removing it from the collection. If the count at the start of the method was 1, it is now 0.

If I retrieve the collection from session again in the same method to check if the collection count is less one, it is.

Simple stuff so far.

On a subsequent request the collection is pulled from session again, but instead of having a count of 0 as expect, it has 1. The previously removed item has not been removed! Why is this?

Though if enough requests are made, the count does indeed end up as zero. It's as if it takes 30 seconds or so for the session object to synchronise across all threads.

Can this really be so? Is MVC4 (could be previous versions too?) have some odd session synchronisation problems?

I'm using the default InProc session provider and settings.

Here's the log:

```
Thread  Level   Logger  Message
23  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Pre-processing - Tasks.Count: 1
23  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - SessionID: asaq1v5afu0pwz13at4a24hl
23  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - Tasks.Count: 0

16  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Pre-processing - Tasks.Count: 1
16  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - SessionID: asaq1v5afu0pwz13at4a24hl
16  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - Tasks.Count: 0

23  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Pre-processing - Tasks.Count: 1
23  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - SessionID: asaq1v5afu0pwz13at4a24hl
23  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - Tasks.Count: 0

24  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Pre-processing - Tasks.Count: 1
24  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - SessionID: asaq1v5afu0pwz13at4a24hl
24  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - Tasks.Count: 0

9   DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Pre-processing - Tasks.Count: 1
9   DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - SessionID: asaq1v5afu0pwz13at4a24hl
9   DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - Tasks.Count: 0

14  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Pre-processing - Tasks.Count: 1
14  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - SessionID: asaq1v5afu0pwz13at4a24hl
14  DEBUG   ProjectMvc.Controllers.RpcController    Post processing - Tasks.Count: 0
```

If I can't work out why the collection in session is not being updated for other requests I'll have to work around it and store this stuff in a database.

Here's the code:

```
    public ActionResult GetCoordinatesTask()
    {
        var user = Session["User"] as IUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            Logger.LogError(this, "No user in session!");
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        if (user.PhotoGeocodingTasks == null || user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count == 0)
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        lock (user.PhotoGeocodingTasks)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug(this, "Pre-processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count" + user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count);

            var task = user.PhotoGeocodingTasks[0];
            if (!user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Remove(task))
                Logger.LogError(this, "Could not remove geocoding task after picking it up!");

            var encodedTask = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"photoid", task.PhotoId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)},
                {"latlong", task.Latitude + "," + task.Longitide}
            };

            Logger.LogDebug(this, "Post processing - SessionID: " + Session.SessionID);
            Logger.LogDebug(this, "Post processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count" + user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count);

            return Json(encodedTask, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Here's what I have on the web.config for session:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
        <providers>
            <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

**Edit 2**

I also tried storing this task data in the HttpRuntime.Cache as well (keyed against a user id) and got the same result. No updated values for other requests. It's like synchronisation is disabled in my configuraiton.

I've tried this code on two computers as well, same result.

Comment: Session has nothing to do with MVC.

Comment: Actually I don't know if the threads ever do synchronise as my code stops calling this method after a while :(

Comment: I'm voting to have this question deleted as "not constructive," since you figured out that it was actually developer error.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see this behaviour here. Can you try my sample?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using NLog;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

namespace Mvc4Application.Controllers
{
    public class GeoCodingTask
    {
       public string  Photoid{get;set;}
    }

    public class User
    {
        public List<GeoCodingTask> PhotoGeocodingTasks {get;set;}
    }

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public ActionResult SetupCoordinatesTask()
        {   
                User  user = new User{ PhotoGeocodingTasks = new List<GeoCodingTask>()};
                 user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Add(new GeoCodingTask{ Photoid= "id1"});
                 user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Add(new GeoCodingTask { Photoid = "id2" });
                Session["User"] = user ;

            return View("GetCoordinatesTask");
        }

        public ActionResult GetCoordinatesTask()
        {
            User user = (User)Session["User"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                _logger.Error("No user in session!");
                return View();
            }
            if (user.PhotoGeocodingTasks == null )
                _logger.Debug("PhotoGeocodingTasks - null " );
            if (user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count == 0)
            {
                _logger.Debug("Pre-processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count" + user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count);
                return View();
            }
            lock (user.PhotoGeocodingTasks)
            {
                _logger.Debug("Pre-processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count" + user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count);
                var task = user.PhotoGeocodingTasks[0];
                if (!user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Remove(task))
                    _logger.Error("Could not remove geocoding task after picking it up!");

                _logger.Debug("Post processing - SessionID: " + Session.SessionID);
                _logger.Debug("Post processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count" + user.PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count);
                return View();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I first call http://localhost:1631/home/SetupCoordinatesTask to setup the session and then on 2 times http://localhost:1631/home/GetCoordinatesTask

The result is

```
thread:19|2012-01-20 22:12:51.0492|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Pre-processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count2
thread:19|2012-01-20 22:12:51.0652|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Post processing - SessionID: e4tawytx2mfq2msc3y2ajzl3
thread:19|2012-01-20 22:12:51.0652|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Post processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count1
thread:10|2012-01-20 22:13:01.0928|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Pre-processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count1
thread:10|2012-01-20 22:13:01.0928|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Post processing - SessionID: e4tawytx2mfq2msc3y2ajzl3
thread:10|2012-01-20 22:13:01.0928|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Post processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count0
thread:15|2012-01-20 22:13:02.6698|DEBUG|Mvc4Application.Controllers.HomeController|Pre-processing - PhotoGeocodingTasks.Count0
```

Can you simplify tyour code and post a complete sample?

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time Malcom. I replicated your sample and it works as expected, adds a task, then retrieves it and removes it from session.

Before your reply I also wrote some new code to stick the tasks in the HttpRuntime cache and got the same bad effect of no cross-thread /request updates (which makes sense after reading documentation that says session is stored under the cache anyhow).

Feels like a config issue.

Comment: I've compared the web.configs between the two apps and tried some differences but same result.

Answer (score 1):

Developer error. Embarrassing, but I had a bug where I kept creating a new task after processing the last one. I'm tempted to delete this question :)

Thanks for your time all the same Malcom.

Comment: Jay - developer error - surly not :)

Comment: I know, shocking behaviour.